# PhoneGap, IOs & Vimeo

Tags: ios, cordova, vimeo

I'm trying to link to videos on vimeo within my PhoneGap application and I would like them to play inside the app (Fullscreen and when done button is pressed go back to app). Does anyone know how to pull off this kind of functionality. I've looked at vimeo's API's but they seem to just pull the video links in and then link out to the video. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The Iframe tag that comes by default in the share option will work in phone gap.

Note:You need a pro account to use some thing other then the iframe